# Interference of atomic orbitals: In what field do atomic orbitals oscillate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, interference, orbitals

I am learning molecular orbital theory for chemical applications. To understand why molecular orbitals can be antibonding, destructive interference aka out-of-phase interference of the orbital oscillation is described.

What does negative/positive sign mean in regard to the orbitals? What is the physical dimension in which this is oscillating? Is it the electromagnetic field?

Related: [Physical intuition behind negative values for wave function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201250/)

Update: I think I understand now that each particle is in itself a representation of its own field. Specifically according to QED there is an electron field and an electromagnetic aka photon field. So the answer would be: The electron field.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think the destructive interference is due to the orbitals oscillating? What you're describing is the LCAO approach to constructing bonds, and this has nothing to do with oscillations.

Comment: Thank you! For me I assumed destructive interference needs two standing waves (I called that oscillations) in a certain field.

Comment: Nikole, do you still need the question answered? If so perhaps you could edit the question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I have not found an answer yet.

Comment: I think I understand now, each particle is in itself a representation of its own field. Specifically according to QED there is an electron field and an electromagnetic aka photon field. So the answer is: The electron field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current understanding, orbitals or wavefunctions are nothing more or nothing less than functions which solve the Schroedinger equation and have an [L2 norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function) of 1. That they "interfere" is equivalent to the statement that the Schroedinger equation is linear. The reason why this abstract concept is invoked so often, rather than one which refers to a physical space, is ultimately empirical. The formalism based on integrating these [probability density functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) agrees with statistical fluctuations seen in experiments.

Assigning a more concrete meaning to this, be it an extra dimension or field, is a matter of choosing a [quantum interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics). Moving from a wavefunction which characterizes the uncertainty in a particle's position to a wavefunctional which characterizes the uncertainty in a field's shape (QFT) cannot help one escape this.

Comment: Thank you! I very much appreciate your answer, as it describes to lay people some of the background behind these interpretations.